# pd.read_csv ignores columns that don't have headers

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a .csv file that is generated by a third-party program. The data in the file is in the following format:

```
%m/%d/%Y    49.78   85  6   15                      
03/01/1984  6.63368 82  7   9.8 34.29056405 2.79984079  2.110346498 0.014652412 2.304545521 0.004732732
03/02/1984  6.53368 68  0   0.2 44.61471002 3.21623666  2.990408898 0.077444779 2.793385466 0.02661873
03/03/1984  4.388344    55  6   0   61.14463457 3.637231063 3.484310818 0.593098236 3.224973641 0.214360796
```

There are 5 column headers (row 1 in excel, columns A-E) but 11 columns in total (row 1 columns F-K are empty, rows 2-N contain float values for columns A-K)

I was not sure how to paste the .csv lines in so they are easily replicable, sorry for that. An image of the excel sheet is shown here: [Excel sheet to read in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsJnk.png)

when I use the following code:

```
FWInds=pd.read_csv("path.csv")
```

or:

```
FWInds=pd.read_csv("path.csv", header=None)
```

the resulting dataframe FWInds does not contain the last 6 columns - it only contains the columns with headers (columns A-E from excel, column A as index values).

```
FWIDat.shape
Out[48]: (245, 4)
```

Ultimately the last 6 columns are the only ones I even want to read in.

I also tried:

```
FWInds=pd.read_csv('path,csv', header=None, index_col=False)
```

but got the following error

```
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 2, saw 11
```

I also tried to ignore the first row since the column titles are unimportant:

```
FWInds=pd.read_csv('path.csv', header=None, skiprows=0)
```

but get the same error.

Also no luck with the "usecols" parameter, it doesn't seem to understand that I'm referring to the column numbers (not names), unless I'm doing it wrong:

```
FWInds=pd.read_csv('path.csv', header=None, usecols=[5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

Any tips? I'm sure it's an easy fix but I'm very new to python.

Comment: So, you want to keep columns F → K and drop the first 5 columns?

Comment: Yes. Though if I can just read in all of the columns I can do that easily within python. Either way works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of parameters that can be passed to `pd.read_csv()`:

```
import pandas as pd
colnames = list('ABCDEFGHIKL')
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='\t', names=colnames)
```

With this, I can actually import your data quite fine (and it is accessible via eg `df['K']` afterwards).

Comment: This works except I need to use sep=","....... This is my own fault because of the way I copied the data into the question directly from the .csv in excel.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it as shown:

```
col_name = list('ABCDEFGHIJK')
data = 'path.csv'
pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace=True, header=None, names=col_name, usecols=col_name[5:])
```

[image]

To read all the columns from A → K, simply omit the `usecols` parameter.

---

Data:

```
data = StringIO(
'''
%m/%d/%Y,49.78,85,6,15                      
03/01/1984,6.63368,82,7,9.8,34.29056405,2.79984079,2.110346498,0.014652412,2.304545521,0.004732732
03/02/1984,6.53368,68,0,0.2,44.61471002,3.21623666,2.990408898,0.077444779,2.793385466,0.02661873
03/03/1984,4.388344,55,6,0,61.14463457,3.637231063,3.484310818,0.593098236,3.224973641,0.214360796
''')

col_name = list('ABCDEFGHIJK')
pd.read_csv(data, header=None, names=col_name, usecols=col_name[5:])
```

Comment: This produces an error: Too many columns specified: expected 11 and found 1. If I omit the usecols parameter, it works but the values within the dataframe are all nan

Comment: It works fine for the data that you've provided. This error occurs mainly due to `sep` not matching the format of the data.

Comment: Try playing with the `sep` parameter and tune it accordingly to suit your format, Like `sep='\s+'`

Comment: I uploaded a picture of the .csv file open in excel. I hope that helps - I basically copied and pasted that into the question so that pasted data may not be representative of the actual sep!

Comment: Simply provide `sep=','` and remove `delim_whitespace` from `read_csv` which is the default separator.

Comment: Thanks. If I use sep="," and specify the column names as you've shown (names=col_name), it works. The other parameters were not required. I still cannot use the usecols parameter though but now that it's in python I can work with the data. Thanks!

Comment: *See edit*. It works even then and you don't need to provide `sep=','` as it is interpreted as default itself.